# ratio of running times when N doubled in big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, division

I learned that,using Big O notation

```
O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) -> O(max(f(n),g(n))

O( f(n) )* O( g(n)) -> O( f(n) g(n))
```

but now, I have this equation for running time T for input size N

```
T(N) = O(N^2)  // O of N square
```

I need to find the ratio `T(2N) / T(N)`

I tried this

```
T(2N) / T(N) --> O((2N)^2) /O( N^2)  --> 4
```

Is this correct? Or is the above division invalid?

Comment: Keep in mind that T(2N) = T(N) (or O(2*N²) = O(N²), since its a constant)

Comment: so when inupt is doubled ,the ratio of the running times = 1 ? that seems illogical.. or am I confused?

Comment: I'm not a professional in big-o-notation or something, but f(n) in O(n) still means: f(n) grows asympthotic faster than n. even if f(n) = n*1000000000000000000000000000000000000 or something :D

Comment: Due to T(n) not being given explicitly, all we can say is that T(2n)/T(n) is in O(1). If T(n) were in Θ(a^n), this would not be true; in that case, T(2n)/T(n) would be in Θ(a^n) as well since a^2n = (a^n)^2 and thus (a^2n)/(a^n) = a^n, ignoring whatever constants and terms in o(a^n) might be hidden in T(n).

Comment: @G.Bach I thought that too at first, and started writing an answer to that effect, but got part-way through and changed my mind. I now think T(2n)/T(n) could even be O(n^2)!

Comment: @TooTone I read your answer, you're right.

Comment: Taking a simple common-sense view, all we have is an upper limit on T(N) and an upper limit on T(2N). If we were looking at a function that increased with both, such as their sum, we could try to use that to construct an upper limit on f(T(N),T(2N)). For division, we can't because the ratio increases with decreasing T(N), and we have no lower limit on T(N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also say this is incorrect. My intuition was that if `T(N)` is `O(N^2)`, then `T(2N)/T(N)` is `O(1)`, consistent with your suggestion that `T(2N)/T(N) = 4`. I think however that the *intuition is wrong*.

Consider a counter-example.

Let `T(N)` be 1 if `N` is odd, and `N^2` if `N` is even, as below.

[image]

This is clearly `O(N^2)`, because we can choose a constant `p=1`, such that `T(N) ≤ pN^2` for sufficiently large `N`.

What is `T(2N)`? This is `(2N)^2 = 4N^2`, as below, because `2N` is always even.

[image]

Hence `T(2N)/T(N)` is `4N^2/1 = 4N^2` when `N` is odd, and `4N^2/N^2=4` when `N` is even, as below.

[image]

Clearly `T(2N)/T(N)` is not 4. It is, however, `O(N^2)`, because we can choose a constant `q=4` such that `T(2N)/T(N) ≤ qN^2` for sufficiently large `N`.

R code for the plots below

```
x=1:50
t1=ifelse(x%%2, 1, x^2)
plot(t1~x,type="l")

x2=2*x
t2=ifelse(x2%%2, 1, x2^2)
plot(t2~x,type="l")

ratio=t2/t1
plot(ratio~x,type="l")
```

This problem is an interesting one and strikes me as belonging in the realm of pure mathematics, i.e. limits of sequences and the like. I am not trained in pure mathematics and I would be nervous of claiming that `T(2N)/T(N)` is *always* `O(N^2)`, as it might be possible to invent some rather tortuous counter-examples.

Comment: Suppose `T(2N+1)` is zero, and `T(2N)` is `N^2`. Then there is no finite upper bound on `T(2N)/T(N)`. For odd N greater than 0, it will be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Even if T(N) = Θ(N²) (big-theta) this doesn't work. (I'm not even going to talk about big-O.)

```
c1 * N² <= T(N) <= c2 * N²
c1 * 4 * N² <= T(2N) <= c2 * 4 * N²

T(N) = c_a * N² + f(N)
T(2N) = c_b * 4 * N² + g(N)
```

For c_a and c_b somewhere between c1 and c2, and f(N) and g(N) small-o of N². (Thanks G. Bach!) And there is nothing to guarantee that the quotient will be equal to 4 since both c_a, c_b, f(N) and g(N) can be all sorts of things. For example, take c_a = 1, c_b = 2 and f(N) = g(N) = 0. Divide them and you get

```
T(2N)/T(N) = (2 * 4 * N²)/N² = 8
```

Comment: Even this is incorrect/incomplete since there may be terms in T(n) that are o(N^2) (the less-known small-o describes functions that grow strictly smaller than f(n)).

Comment: @TooTone Hurp durp durp I can't into math AT ALL today. :(

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

This is incorrect.

Running time is not the same as time complexity(here Big O).Time complexity says like it can't have a running time worse that a constant times **N^2**.Running time can be quite different, maybe very low, maybe close to the asymptotic limit.That purely depends on the **hidden constants**.If someone asked you this question, it's a trick question.

Hidden constants refers to the actual number of primitive instructions carried out.So in this case the total number of operations could be:

```
5*N^2
```

or

```
1000*N^2.
```

or maybe

```
100*N^2+90N
```

or maybe just

```
100*N (Recall this is also O(N^2))
```

The factor depends on the implementation and the actual instructions carried out.This is found out from the algorithm.
So whichever the case we simply say the Big-O is **O(N^2)**.

Comment: What "hidden constants" do you mean? Could you explain that relating to the question? Now I'm curios :)

Comment: there was a mention in `sedgwick's algorithms` book about `preferring ~ over BigO` when considering performance ..he reasons that using ~ the `doubling ratio test` can be justified where as using bigO cannot.. so I was trying out the equations

Comment: @damon:I don't get you there, could you elaborate?

Comment: could you refer last paragraph in page 206 of sedgewick's book..says running time of some algorithm may be both `O(N^2)` and `~a N^b log N` .. Therefore O notaion may not justify a `doubling ratio test` for this algorithm

Comment: I don't have sedgewick.Or I would have referred it before.Anyway what is that test for?

Comment: doubling ratio test tries to find the value of ratio of running times of an algorithm when input size is doubled in each iteration.. over a  large number of iterations the ratio begins to approach a number say 8. If for an `input size=1000`,the running time=`0.10s`, then we predict that for an `input size=2000`, the running time will be `0.80s`

Comment: @damon: As you can see in the given link, doubling ratio is measured using running time, not the time complexity.